# ScheduledExecutorService and its schedule method. How it works?

Tags: java, concurrency, scheduled-tasks, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I have such code:

```
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        scheduledExecutorService.schedule(() ->
                System.out.println("Hello" + Thread.currentThread().getName()), 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    scheduledExecutorService.schedule(() ->
            System.out.println("Hello first " + Thread.currentThread().getName()), 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
```

I was debugging this code and I was surprised method Thread.start() was executed only one time.
What happens with thread when I execute this schedule method? Is it in wait or blocked set or where else?

Answer (score 0):

[Executors.newScheduledThreadPool](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java7/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newScheduledThreadPool(int)) creates a thread pool with fixed number of threads:

> Creates a thread pool that can schedule commands to run after a given delay, or to execute periodically.
>
> Parameters:
> `corePoolSize` - the number of threads to keep in the pool, even if they are idle.

All tasks scheduled for execution with this instance of executor service will be processed in a single thread.

> Q: What happens with thread when I execute this schedule method? Is it in wait or blocked set or where else?

The thread is waiting for new tasks to execute and may terminate depending on the configuration of the thread pool - see [ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask()](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java#L996).

Comment: Yea, I got it. But my question is about schedule method itself. How it works and what happens with thread when task is added to queue?

Comment: Could you describe please why method Thread.start() is executed only once - when schedule() method has been started?

Comment: Single thread is created and started by the pool to service all tasks submitted to this pool. It does not make sense to start the thread more than once.